# Vue-cil distributed app deploy error on digital ocean - TypeError: t is not a function

Tags: deployment, webpack, digital-ocean, vuejs2

I am deploying a Vue 2.0 SPA app to digital ocean. App is build with vue-cli webpack template and when deployed I get this error and can't figure it out...

TypeError: t is not a function

[image]

App was buit directly on the server and build was ok, no errors. Using Node v6.9.5 with latest released versions of vue and vue related packages.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out the problem was in my `vue-router` setup and I was running old version of vue-router locally. API changed a bit in the latest versions...